# How to check the raw sql statement of getting the foreign key set of a model instance?

Tags: django

I have two models `User` and `Post` like this:

```
class User(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField('username', max_length=10)

class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)

u1 = User.objects.get(pk=1)
```

How can I find the raw sql statement of `u1.post_set`, there seems no api for this.

Comment: Exactly like @Sayse said, but print it or wrap in `str()`

Comment: @Sayse thanks. that's it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [get the queryset](https://github.com/django/django/blob/d30febb4e59b659e0d279c77f61f936c199a05b2/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py#L586) of the `RelatedManager` and then get the query of that queryset

```
u1.post_set.get_queryset().query
```

This should turn into something like

```
'SELECT (some fields) FROM "the _set model" WHERE "_set_model"."model.id" = 1'
```

Comment: How do you  know `get_queryset`? I check the `u1.post_set.__dict__` and get nothing useful.

Comment: I look into the source code, easiest way to find it is to search for "github django", in this case, I then use github's search to find the class `RelatedManager`, sometimes "github django relatedmanager" will take you there